# Specflow tests not initiating

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

I keep getting this error when trying to run my Specflow tests. I've tried deleting the bin, deleted all nuget packages and reinstalled them, modified the

```
app.config, but this error still persist 


Test Name:  CreateAnEmailCampaign

Result Message: 
OneTimeSetUp: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Configuration system failed to initialize
  ----> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Unrecognized configuration section sectionGroup. (C:\Users\bin\Debug\Demo.dll.config line 11)


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>


  <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
    <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </sectionGroup>
  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <specFlow>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config --><!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config --><unitTestProvider name="NUnit" /></specFlow></configuration>
```

Comment: please post your app.config

Comment: Please share app.config and Demo.dll.config

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan app.config added

Comment: The dll.config has the same code as the app.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the appconfig you have posted, the element `sectionGroup` is not a child of `configSections` and thus the error -

> Unrecognized configuration section sectionGroup.

To solve this problem, move the `sectionGroup` inside the `configSections` as shown below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <specFlow>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see   http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
    <unitTestProvider name="NUnit" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```